# listview startactivty on click item

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I'm trying to start an activity when the user clicks on an item in the `listview`. In the adapter below, I get problems in `intent` and in the onClick. What could be causing the failure?
 ok after update the code is missing }};}}  character like  after editing my code and

my code 
    return rowView;

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
       int itemPosition     = position;
       String  itemValue= (String)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
if (itemValue.equals("1")){
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Spain.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("2")) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, As.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if(itemValue.equals("3")){
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Ma.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if(itemValue.equals("4")) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Me.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("5")){ 
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Gr.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
 else if(itemValue.equals("6")) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Th.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if(itemValue.equals("7")) {  
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Ukr.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("8")){
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Po.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("9")) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(context, France.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("10")){
Intent intent = new Intent(context, UK.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("11")) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Ksa.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("12"))  {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Ger.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("13"))  {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Canda.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("14")){
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Turkey.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("15"))    {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Italy.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("16")) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Russia.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("17")) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, China.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
else if (itemValue.equals("18")) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Usa.class);
context.startActivity(intent);}
      })};}
```

Comment: "i get the problem" - What problem do you get?

Comment: any error while selecting the list item?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Ksa.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Ksa.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

In your adapter class why did you declare a listview and call the `onItemClickListener` method?  You haven't initialized your listView either.

***NOTE:*** This code will work when you click item from adapter class.

Comment: ok that good i tried it but now im getting this error the method startactivty(intent) is undefined

Comment: ok now my code missing character like };})  what is missing in it please

Comment: Check The Code Please My Code After Update

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code

1. There is no need to have an instance of List view in your adapter, and also that List View is not initialized this will cause  null pointer exception
2. In this line `String  itemValue= (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);` you are trying to get an item from List View which is not initialized and you are not using the  values which you initialized in the adapter Ideally that line should look like this

   `String itemValue=values[position]`
3. In your `OnItemClickListener` the code in both if and else parts are doing the same work and you should use `context` instead of `this`.

Comment: so your opinion is to remove this with context and change string itemvalue to values position in the listview activty

Comment: yes..and also remove the listview reference from adapter and   It's better to move your  onItemclickListener to the fragment contaning listview